# How use a cron job php?

Tags: php, cron, jobs

I have to work with cron job and i read something about that like 
* * * * *   /usr/bin/wget http://blablaba/cron.php
(i know how set time m ex. run every minute).
My question is where i have to put that code?
in php index?
like:

Comment: It belongs in a users a the system `crontab`. Read about that in the man page for the cron deamon or the crontab command.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it will be for users to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should put all cron jobs into `crontab` with

```
crontab -e
```

As far as I know it's the same for all Linux distros and Mac OS. As for Windows, just save yourself a trouble and go for Vagrant virtual machine

Answer (score 0):

I usually put this command in WEBMIN.
Ask your hosting, where do you need to configure crons jobs.
For example in CPANEL:[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit it with PHP directly.
You need to add new cron jobs using console command:

```
crontab -e
```

or add new files to the /etc/cron.d directory.

Answer (score -1):

Best if you create a new file under /etc/cron.d directory which is where you should put your own cron jobs.